# Metal texture not rendered as expected when sampler set to pixel

Tags: textures, pixel, metal

I have a 6x6 chessboard texture (see first image below) that I render on another texture of the same dimension using a quad. Basically, I'm copying the texture to another texture. The sampler filter is set to Nearest and coord to Pixel so I would have thought to have to pass (0,0), (5,0), (5,0), (5,5) which are the coordinates of the texture corners. However, the texture is not rendered as expected using those coords. See image below. I would have expected the result to be the same as the source. Using (0,0), (6,0), (6,0), (6,6) render the texture correctly. This doesn't make sense to me as three of the coords are outside the source texture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect texel coordinates are at (0.5, 0.5) and not at the whole numbers and this is working as expected

Comment: This is also my conclusion after more testing. Thanks!